# Create UIImage from raw data

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am currently doing image modification. I used a class of my own named "Image".

It looks like this:

```
@interface Image : NSObject {
    @public
        int height;
        int width;
        float* data;
}
```

So in data I have floats, in rgba format which mean they go four by four. I can't change my Image class.

I need to create a UIImage from my Image. I'm trying something like that:

```
+(UIImage *)getUIImageFromImage:(Image *)_img {
    NSData * imageData = (NSData *) _img->data;
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is my cast to (NSData *) okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it ain't. `NSData` is an Objective-C object. `float *` is a raw pointer to one or more `float` values.

If you tell us where this data comes from and what format it's in, we may be able to suggest a way to convert it to either an `NSData` object or to a `CGImage` Quartz value, which can then be wrapped in a `UIImage` and used with `UIKit` classes.

Comment: This data is just float values (I hope I'm answering right) between 0.0 and 255.0

Comment: You'll have to manually transform it into values that can be used by `CGImageCreate()` (probably an array of `uint8_t` values.) There is no inbuilt support for building images from that sort of data.

Comment: Thank you. Can't make it work tough, can't figure out how to use the CGDataProviderRef parameter...

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `CGDataProvider`? It explains how to use it.

Comment: I finally succeeded ! It was way easier, just had to create a unsigned char * rawData, fill it with my data, then create a context with CGBitmapContextCreate (with rawData in parameters), and finally use CGBitmapContextCreateImage :)